# How to use PDO::exec() with PDO::bindParam()?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to execute UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE, binding params and counting affected rows.

E.g.

```
<?php
// Class UserProfData ... new PDO() ...

$query = "UPDATE CadUsers
          SET aboutme = :aboutme
          WHERE userid = $UserID";

// Any function to bind... using exec() to count affected rows.
$instance->bindParam(':aboutme', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR); // 'My name is Mark Larry B. Gates.'

$Affected_Rows = $instance->exec($query); // Affected: [false/NULL/0/1] rows
?>
```

`PDO::prepare()` + `bindParam()` + `execute()` doesn't work.

Comment: Where is the `prepare` :P?

Comment: Prepare + bindParam + exec() doesn't work too.

Comment: 1. Is `$UserID` an int or a string?

Comment: 2. Are you doing `$instance = $connection_variable_here->prepare($query);`?

Comment: 3. Try `echo $colour;` and see if it's the value you want.

Comment: 4. Try `print_r($connection_variable_here->errorInfo());` at the end of your code.

Comment: 5. Paste the whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use PDO::exec() with PDO::bindParam().

PDO::prepare() + execute() + rowCount() have to be used instead. You should always use the proper way, even if it doesn't work at the moment due to some error you made. You have to fix that error instead of trying the wrong way.

Note that you should bind **all** variables that are used in the query

```
$query = "UPDATE CadUsers SET aboutme = ? WHERE userid = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([$color, $UserID]);
$rows = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Comment: Works! Thank you very much!